# Query for InfluxDb to select a range of tag keys

Tags: jquery, mysql, influxdb

I need to find a query for InfluxDb to select a range of keys in my database.

I am trying something like this but is not working:

```
select * from <measurement> where "key" > '1' and "key" < 200
```

I can select a range of my field key-values, for example:

```
select * from <measurement> where value > 2000
```

That is working. But for a specific tag key-value range doesn't work. Any thought?

This is related with my other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254073/how-to-select-a-range-of-variables-tags-in-grafana).

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** I can select a range of my field key-values but not for a specific tag-key-value. Range doesn't work.

**A:** Range filters don't work on tag values because they are `string` type.

See: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/concepts/glossary/#tag-value

> **tag value**
>
> The value part of the key-value pair that makes up a tag. Tag values
>   are **strings** and they store metadata. Tag values are indexed so queries
>   on tag values are performant.

Other than building a super long `filter` which includes a number of `OR` conditions, I'm not sure if there is an easier way out for you.

I guess the most sensible solution would be to better structure your scheme in such a way that looking up by `range` is possible. As for how your schema should look like? It really depends on your use case and the type of data you are storing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since my keys are strings, do you know maybe a Regex capable to filter a range of tags, when the tags are numerical string? I am trying this
...key =~ /[1-50]/... 
But it seems to take all my tags again.
 thanks

Comment: @SalvadorVigo you can't write`[1-50]` to match 1 to 50. This is incorrect regular expression. Doing `[1-9]` will match 1-9 and doing `[1-4][0-9]` will match the range 10 - 49.